# Is there a bug with foreign-libs in the cljsbuild repl?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, clojurescript

When I:

1. `clone` the [cljs-webgl](https://github.com/asakeron/cljs-webgl) project,
2. Compile it with:

   `lein cljsbuild once`
3. Start the repl with

   `lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-listen`
4. Paste the following into the REPL

`

```
  (ns learningwebgl.lesson-06
      (:require
        [WebGLUtils]
        [mat4]
        [learningwebgl.common :refer [init-gl init-shaders get-perspective-matrix
                                      get-position-matrix deg->rad animate load-image]]
        [cljs-webgl.buffers :refer [create-buffer clear-color-buffer clear-depth-buffer draw!]]
        [cljs-webgl.shaders :refer [get-attrib-location]]
        [cljs-webgl.constants.buffer-object :as buffer-object]
        [cljs-webgl.constants.capability :as capability]
        [cljs-webgl.constants.draw-mode :as draw-mode]
        [cljs-webgl.constants.data-type :as data-type]
        [cljs-webgl.constants.texture-parameter-name :as texture-parameter-name]
        [cljs-webgl.constants.texture-filter :as texture-filter]
        [cljs-webgl.constants.webgl :as webgl]
        [cljs-webgl.texture :refer [create-texture]]
        [cljs-webgl.typed-arrays :as ta]))`
```

I get the following:

```
WARNING: No such namespace: WebGLUtils at line 1 <cljs repl>
```

(even though it is defined in the [`project.clj`](https://github.com/asakeron/cljs-webgl/blob/master/project.clj) as:

```
:foreign-libs [
        {:file "resources/js/gl-matrix-min.js" :provides ["mat4","mat3","vec3"]}
        {:file "resources/js/webgl-utils.js" :provides ["WebGLUtils"]}]}
```

My question is: **Is there a bug with foreign-libs in the cljsbuild repl?**

Comment: Not yet - it appears to be a non-trivial fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:foreign-libs` support in ClojureScript REPLs is quite new, and cljs-webgl is using a fairly old version of the compiler without the support.